# How to Add Extra Column into existing Tablix from second dataset

Tags: reporting-services

I have one SSRS report where my data is coming for single building. In the same report now I need to add regional Avg against single building Total.

For example, my report  hierarchy should be: BuildingWise Complaint Type Count, RegionalWise Complaint Avg count, NationalWise Complaint Count. For BuildingWise I need monthly data for last 12 month detailed Count but for regional and national I need only cumulative count.

For more reference I am sharing with report screenshot.

[image]

Comment: It's still not clear what you're asking for. How does the hierarchy relate to your need for a "single building total" and where should that already on the report. Where is the data for this new field coming from? Does it need to be calculated?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are after is the [Lookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ee210531.aspx) function. This allows you to look up results from another dataset depending on values in this dataset. For example, let's say you have a RegionSummary dataset that calculates your average for each region as follows:

```
SELECT RegionCode, Avg(Complaints) AS RegionAverage
FROM Complaints
```

Then in your cell `Value` expression you can look up the regional average for the current row:

```
=Lookup(Fields!RegionCode.Value, Fields!RegionCode.Value, Fields!RegionAverage.Value, "RegionSummary")
```

This looks up the RegionAverage from the RegionSummary dataset by matching the RegionCode of the current row with the RegionCode of the RegionSummary dataset.